# Prove that any subgroup of $F_5$ of index 3 is isomorphic to $F_{13}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology

> Let $F_n$ denote the free group on $n$ elements.  Prove that any subgroup of $F_5$ of index 3 is isomorphic to $F_{13}$.

I noted that the wedge product of 13 copies of $S^1$ is a 3 fold covering of 5 copies of $S^1$.  But how do I prove that every 3-fold covering satisfies this property?

Comment: A cover is a graph.  Collapse a maximal tree to a point, and it becomes a wedge of circles.  Count the number of edges...

Comment: Use the fact that 1) the Euler characteristic is multiplicative under covers and 2) the Euler characteristic of a connected graph determines its fundamental group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M.Hall, *The Theory of Groups*, Theorem 7.2.8:

> Let $U$ be a subgroup of finite index $n$ in a free group $F_r$ with $r$ free generators. Then $U$ is a free group on $1 + n(r-1)$ free generators.

In your case  $1 + n(r - 1)=13$.